# When to use 'if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME'

Tags: ruby

I see many programs being encased by the following `if` statement:

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  # rest of the program
end
```

I read that it is "to make sure that the current file corresponds to the program that needs to [be] executed".

When should I use this statement in my programs? In what situations should I use this? And when is it not necessary?

Comment: Just another use case: Sometimes I add unit tests in this part. Then I can change the code and start the test without leaving my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when is it not necessary?

Almost always.

> when should I use this statement in my programs?

When you have a file that is mainly used by other files, but *sometimes* you want to run the file directly. In this case, this section of the code normally carries some tests or example usage.

```
# animal.rb
class Animal
  def voice
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  def voice
    'Woof!'
  end
end


if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  puts "testing voice"
  puts Dog.new.voice == 'Woof!'
end
```

If you run `ruby animal.rb`, you'll see the debug/testing output. If you just `require 'animal'` from another file, you won't.

Answer (score 3):

When the code is called from another Ruby program as a library, that condition does not hold. When it is the main program that is executed, that condition holds.

Sometimes, you want to program software that can either be used as a library or run as a main program, and want to make it behave differently accordingly. In such case, you use it.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand.